# Concatonating 2 dataframes from dictionary panads

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like this {'ox': dfox, 'dog':dfdog}. The dataframes have columns of themselves. How would I concatenate them together so that I would be able to identify what columns belong to what dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `add_prefix` method:

```
d = {'ox': dfox, 'dog': dfdog}

# pd.merge, pd.concat or whatever you want
dfcomb = pd.merge(dfox.add_prefix('ox_'), dfdog.add_prefix('dog_'), ...)
```

or inside the dict:

```
d1 = {k: v.add_prefix(f'{k}_') for k, v in d.items()}
```